# Taking a Screenshot with a Chrome Extension / SvelteKit App

Tags: google-chrome-extension, sveltekit

I am making a Chrome extension for my SvelteKit app that allows my users to extract text, PDF links, and images.

I am currently using an iframe that points to my Sveltekit App and then communicates with the chrome extension.  This works perfectly for text and links.

However, I would like to give the user the ability to screenshot the page by clicking a button and then giving them the ability to drag a box over a portion of the page and save that image - Not the entire page.

I have looked into different things but they all show the "navigator" from Chrome which I don't want to show. I would like the user to be able to click a button and then "crop" whatever portion of the screen they would like to save.

**What would work best for this? Is there a way where I don't have to use permissions from the Chrome extension and just have my web app be able to capture anything on the screen?**

This information then gets saved into my app where the user can use it.
(The app is for designers the specify products)

This is more of an open-ended question as I am relly not sure what is the best way to go about this.